# Using if expression in getter

Tags: c#, .net, accessor

Is it correct to just use a public *property* or should I rather make a private field `_count`? I have read some info on the topic, but I can't find an answer.

```
public int Count
{
    get
    {
        if (this._feeds.IsValueCreated)
        {
            return this._feeds.Value.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            return this._dbConnection.Table<T>().Count();
        }
    }
}

public FeedRepository(SQLiteConnection dbConnection)
{
    this._dbConnection = dbConnection;
    this._feeds = new Lazy<IList<T>>(() => _dbConnection.Table<T>().ToList());
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do and why you're asking this, what you're concerned about. The basic answer to _"Is it correct?"_ is obtained by asking _"Does it work?"_, if you're concerned about something else, then please explain so.

Comment: Why it could be incorrect?

Comment: Are you concerned about your implementation of the repository pattern? If you're just asking about the *Count* getter, than yes, why not, you don't have to implement the private field.

Comment: I have read about "no complicated logic in getter" so I wonder is not too much.

Comment: Well, it's not *too* complicated, is it? :)

Comment: It's really confusing when *title* suggests something else, *question description* something and *code* something entirely different. Title: `if in getter`, question: `is it correct to use getter`, code: `consideration about the choice to be made between adding a private field and a property`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic example of where a property really shines.

Properties allow you to [encapsulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) data, in this instance `Count` is actually doing some clever stuff as it's being lazily loaded from a DB on first access and then pulled from a local cache. The beauty of a using a property over a field here is you can bury all this logic behind the accessor, and as far as the consumer is concerned they only need to be aware of the `Count` property.

On the other hand, if you used `_count` then the consumer would need to understand that they would have to load this value first or it would need to be loaded prematurely in preparation.

So yes, a property is definitely the way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Smart-UI pattern then there is no problem having logic residing within getters and setters. Sometime our applications are small enough to make this an attractable and easy to use option.

We should keep in mind that the reverse is also true. If it a complex problem we are trying to solve, then we should rethink our domain and how we go about interacting with it. One might argue that putting if statements and other business logic in getters and setters will increase the technical debt in the domain.

an interesting discussion to read is found on programmers: [what should be allow inside getters and setters](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177133/what-should-be-allowed-inside-getters-and-setters)

Hope this helps.

Ps. The smart-ui can also be deemed an anti-pattern depending on the scope of our domain.

Answer (score 1):

This borders on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I will try to ask and answer the question you want to ask:

> I have a readonly `Count` property on my Repository pattern. When the repository has been used to load data, the `Count` property should return the number of records loaded. Otherwise, it should return the `Count` of all records in the underlying table.
>
> Is the code used in the getter to achieve this considered "too much"?

The answer is: no. The getter does exactly what you expect it to. There are two scenarios, so you need an `if`. Maybe you can work around it, but it won't make your code any cleaner.